# Is there a way to delete created custom traces/metric in firebase?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-performance

I was testing traces, metrics, and events in firebase to pick what best suit my project.
Now I want to delete the test data I created.
But I couldn't find a way to manually delete it. Is there a way to do it?
[image: screenshot of firebase console]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have contacted Firebase support and this is their response:

> Currently in Google Analytics for Firebase (GA4F), it is not possible to delete events that has been recorded in our end. You can stop recording the event and eventually it will drift out of the default view (Last 30 days). Take a look at this [documentation](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/9237506)  for further information.
>
> All analytics data will still reside within the Google Analytics property - not within the Firebase project. If you are still in the development phase, I advise that you create a development project for analytics implementation, validation and experimentation, then switch to the final project when everything looks good. You can refer to this blog post discussing staging and production environments.

That was really disappointing. I hope they add this feature in the near future.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know there is currently no way to delete custom traces. You might want to [file a feature request](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/) for that.

In the meantime it is probably best to do your testing in a separate project from the one where you run the app in production.